# Disable Animated PNG from animating in an html page

Tags: javascript, html, png, apng

I'd like to stop an animated PNG from playing on my html page, and be frozen on the first frame. Any ideas to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop an APNG from animating in an HTML browser (that supports APNG); however, you can make an APNG appear to be frozen on its first frame by covering the APNG with a PNG of its first frame.  To start the animation, uncover the APNG.